# limit on each clause of logical-OR - mongo and equivalent sql

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

XY: I am attempting to optimize a frequent set of queries in our system, which looks for `"at most one record matching each uid"` from a large collection (table) containing many documents (records) for each `uid`.  Specifically, the collection is a pre-v5.0 time-series (and I need to apply *both* a `limit` and a `sort`), but as far as i can tell an answer would apply to both operators.  Feel free to correct this if needed.

I'm exploring this because even WITH an index on `uid`, each of these (currently separate) queries must incur a significant amount of duplicate overhead, and there are many `uid`s to query - the HTTP api call round trips, opening the index file and finding the first entry for the given `uid`.  It seems like something the engine could optimize significantly better than multiple queries, even considering the "state" that must be kept as each `$or` is evaluated.

say i have:

```
{ uid: "1000", value: "001" }
{ uid: "1001", value: "101" }
{ uid: "1002", value: "201" }
{ uid: "1000", value: "002" }
{ uid: "1000", value: "003" }
{ uid: "1001", value: "102" }
```

`[{ uid: "1000", value: "001"}, {uid: "1001", value: "101"}]`

would be returned by a query looking like (use of `limit` here is invalid; hence my question):

```
mycollection.find({ $or [ {uid: "1000", $limit: 1}, {uid: "1001", $limit: 1} ] })
                                          ^^^                       ^^^
```

Is this possible in Mongo, or do I need to run two separate queries?

So I can better understand the database terminology relevant here, I'm hoping any answer could also reflect the **~standard sql** - is this also possible in `sql`, and if so what's the equivalent query

Comment: note: the simplified example here would definitely be best solved by a cache, and we intend to for the "latest" query (eg simply {$sort:-1} on timestamp) - but other similar uses involve offsetting into the data, which can't use that optimization.  And regardless, I'd really like to understand what's possible or helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you can use `findOne()` inside `$or` clauses 
i think this is what you are looking for  :

```
db.collection.find({ $or :[ db.collection.findOne({uid:"1000"}), db.collection.findOne({uid: "1001"}) ] })
```

Comment: I assume under the hood this is asyncronous enough to allow the DB to "see" all the queries at once?  Or is the `findOne` evaluated first (index scanned)?  Also, is there a way to do a ~`limit` > 1?